# im sure that to most this is a rather simple question but i was trying to figure how to run a python application off of github

Tags: command-line, bash, python

i cloned the files into my home directory and after following the .MD file and making the directory executable, after i try to run `./iFakeLocation` the command line returns `bash: ./iFakeLocation: is a directory` not sure if this is worth asking but id greatly appreciate anyone willing to answer

Comment: The question is currently too vague to be answerable. Look in that directory for python files. Open an issue on that github page for poor documentation. For an actionable answer, please provide a link in your question.

Comment: You don't run a directory, you run files. Since you seem be talking of a Python application, look for a .py file and run it with `python file.py`.